# How to mock a specific method of a class based View without overriding `self`?

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, django-class-based-views, django-unittest

I am trying to patch a function of a view within a TestCase in django. I have a class:

```
class BaseView(View):

    def _get_data(self):
        self.attribute = self.fancy_stuff()
        self.thing = self.do_other_stuff()
```

I need to mock out self.attribute to an empty list like:

```
_get_data_fake_function():
    self.attribute = []
    self.thing = True
```

An issue is that I'm within a test case like:

```
class MyTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.view = BaseView
        self.view_instance = self.view()

        def test_stuff(self):
            with patch(self.view) as mock_view:
                ?
```

I fear the `self` is going to refer to the TestCase instance, and I'm confused on how to patch in the `with patch(thing) as name` part.
I could patch the view's or the view instance's method, but either way I don't know how the fake function will correctly set the view's `attribute` and `thing`, not the test cases.

Comment: Have you tried patching `fancy_stuff` to return an empty list?

Comment: tried that and realized I have to patch both things `_get_data` does

Comment: You can name that `self` variable whatever you want. It being called `self` is just a convention. If you like, name it `this`, or `that`, or `whatever`.

Comment: either way it sets the TestCase instance the attributes, not the view. See how `self.thing` should be set on `BaseView`, but patching within the test class has them set on the test class

Comment: @codyc4321 I added an answer below, lemme know if it works / if you have other questions

Comment: i tried yesterday and it did work, ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Patch the `_get_data` method on `BaseView` to have a `side_effect` that sets the appropriate instance variables on the view.

```
class MyTests(TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.view = BaseView
        with patch.object(self.view, '_get_data', side_effect=view_data_mock):
            self.view_instance = self.view()

    def test_stuff(self):
        self.assertEqual([], self.view_instance.attribute)
        self.assertTrue(self.view_instance.thing)

def view_data_mock(view):
    view.attribute = []
    view.thing = True
```